# Is it possible to organize my profile page?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, design

On my profile page, my order of interest for the content is:

1. Questions (view most frequently)
2. Reputation
3. Answers
4. Tags
5. Profile  (view less frequently)

I can show less info on my profile, but I still have to scroll down to see the areas I'm interested in. It would be great if I could swap the Questions and Answers frames for example.

Is this possible?

Comment: You could write a custom css style and apply it using your browser of choice. Or a userscript to hide/move parts around.

Comment: @J. Steen - thanks for the response.  Though, I was hoping that stackoverflow provided an easier way (point and click) to customize the homepage.

Comment: I believe this would go into 'status-declined'.

Comment: @mtk - do you have more information to substantiate your belief?

Comment: @Chris, [all features start at minus 100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx)?

Comment: @Chris, this is a change that won't affect anything and is purely a representation change. It's just that some users would find it useful. Many users won't even use it. But with my experience on meta such changes get low priority.

Comment: Frédéric & mtk - thanks for the useful info.